# Pythonic way of Implementing this conditional filter

Tags: python

Given that `clusterLists` is a list of lists containing tuples:

```
clusterLists = [[(1.182, "monthly_1"), (1.181, '0_Retrace_3_H1')]
                , [(1.1502, '1_Retrace_5_M15'), (1.1493, '1_Retrace_5_M15')]]
```

I can filter the list as follows:

```
for clust in clusterLists:
    if not sum([x[1].endswith("_M15") for x in clust]) >= 2:
        if not sum([x[1].endswith("_H1") for x in clust]) >= 2:
            print(clust)
```

output:

```
[(1.182, 'monthly_1'), (1.181, '0_Retrace_3_H1')]
```

How do I perform this conditional check in a more pythonic way and achieve the same output. i.e. checks that `if not sum([x[1].endswith("_H6")` etc without adding a line for each.

Comment: Are all the sums you're checking against `2`, or can that vary?

Comment: Currently 2 but I currently have the option to check for more and don't want to lose that @CrazyChucky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's always the last `_<value>` that you're going to use as a condition, I might just use a `collections.Counter` to get all the sums together with that as a key, and then you can just check them all at once:

```
In [187]: from collections import Counter
     ...: conditions = ["M15", "H1"]
     ...: for clust in clusterLists:
     ...:     c = Counter()
     ...:     for val, name in clust:
     ...:         c[name.split("_")[-1]] += val
     ...:     if all(c[cond] < 2 for cond in conditions):
     ...:         print(clust)

[(1.182, 'monthly_1'), (1.181, '0_Retrace_3_H1')]
```

If the logic changes from field to field, you can easily extend that by specifying it in the list too:

```
In [188]: from collections import Counter
     ...: conditions = [("M15", lambda x: x < 2), ("H1", lambda x: x < 2)]
     ...: for clust in clusterLists:
     ...:     c = Counter()
     ...:     for val, name in clust:
     ...:         c[name.split("_")[-1]] += val
     ...:     if all(cond(c[col]) for col, cond in conditions):
     ...:         print(clust)

[(1.182, 'monthly_1'), (1.181, '0_Retrace_3_H1')]
```

EDIT: I see now that you were actually trying to count the occurrences, not sum the associated values. That's pretty easily fixed here by just swapping `+= val` with `+= 1` or by using `Counter`'s ability to take a list as input as below:

```
In [5]: conditions = ["M15", "H1"]
   ...: for clust in clusterLists:
   ...:    c = Counter([name.split("_")[-1] for _, name in clust])
   ...:    if all(c[cond] < 2 for cond in conditions):
   ...:        print(clust)
   ...:
[(1.182, 'monthly_1'), (1.181, '0_Retrace_3_H1')]
```

Comment: If I use the following input `clusterLists = [[(1.182, "monthly_1.182"), (1.181, '0_Retrace_382_H1')],
                [(0.9208000000000001, '0_Retrace_50_H1'), (0.9215000000000001, '1_Retrace_618_H1')]]` the check doesn't remove the two H1 entries.  Would be interested in your feedback please.

Comment: Should it be removing them? `(0.920 + 0.921) < 2`

Comment: Looks like a  misunderstanding.  The < 2 is to check that there are less than 2 per cluster ending with the string "M15" (or "H1 in this instance").  My code works but your solution appeared to be more scalable.    I should have tested this in more detail before accepting.  My mistake.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Read too quickly and thought you were summing the values, but you're actually summing the `True` values. Will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it might help you to know that, while it wouldn't eliminate any lines, you can save a lot of unnecessary indentation if you use `and` vs. a lot of nested `if`s:

```py
for cluster in clusters:
    if (
        not sum([x[1].endswith("_M15") for x in cluster]) >= 2
        and not sum([x[1].endswith("_H1") for x in cluster]) >= 2
    ):
        print(cluster)
```

That way, if you added conditions, your inner code wouldn't have to be indented more and more.

But to actually answer your question, you can define a function like below, and then adding conditions requires only adding entries to the `conditions` dictionary, without repeating yourself unnecessarily:

```py
def less_than(cluster, suffix, cutoff):
    return sum(x[1].endswith(f'_{suffix}') for x in cluster) < cutoff

clusters = [
    [(1.182, "monthly_1"), (1.181, '0_Retrace_3_H1')],
    [(1.1502, '1_Retrace_5_M15'), (1.1493, '1_Retrace_5_M15')]
]

conditions = {'M15': 2, 'H1': 2}

for cluster in clusters:
    if all(less_than(cluster, suffix, cutoff)
           for suffix, cutoff in conditions.items()):
        print(cluster)
```

Note that, like your original answer, this will iterate through the each cluster twice (or more, as you add conditions). This could become a performance issue if you end up with a very long cluster list and/or a great many conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a function and reuse your code:

```
def check_endings(cluster, ending, limit):
    return not sum([x[1].endswith(ending) for x in clust]) >= limit

clusters_to_print = [
    cluster for cluster in clusterLists
    if check_endings(cluster, ending="_M15", limit=2)
    and check_endings(cluster, ending="_H1", limit=2)
]

for cluster in clusters_to_print:
    print(cluster)
```

Technically, this uses more lines even when you don't count the function, but only because the list comprehension is split across them for readability.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe create an array of conditions.

```
cluster_list = [
    [(1.182, "monthly_1"), (1.181, '0_Retrace_3_H1')],
    [(1.1502, '1_Retrace_5_M15'), (1.1493, '1_Retrace_5_M15')]
]
conditions = ["_M15", "_H1", "_H6"]

for cluster in cluster_list:
    matches = [[x[1].endswith(condition) for x in cluster] for condition in conditions]
    if all([not sum(i) >= 2 for i in matches]):
        print(cluster)

# [(1.182, 'monthly_1'), (1.181, '0_Retrace_3_H1')]
```

Comment: I don't get the same output

Comment: now it should work.  (I messed up the pasting to answer field)